# Spring jdbcTemplate retrieve numeric values from query

Tags: java, spring, spring-data, spring-jdbc

I have this query for my jdbcTemplate and I wanna get just the long value from the database, what should be fixed here?

```
String query = "SELECT size from users where name = ? AND type = ?";
long size = jdbcTemplate.query(query, new Object[]{id, type}, (rs, rowNum) -> 
rs.getLong("size"));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
long size = jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(query, Long.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the [`query`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcOperations.html#query-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object:A-org.springframework.jdbc.core.RowMapper-) javadocs in `JdbcOperations` it states:

> **Deprecated.** as of 5.3, in favor of [query(String, RowMapper, Object...)](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcOperations.html#query-java.lang.String-org.springframework.jdbc.core.RowMapper-java.lang.Object...-)

So you can use it like this:

```java
List<Long> sizeResults = jdbcTemplate.query(query, (rs, rowNum) ->
        rs.getLong("size"), id, type);
if (sizeResults.isEmpty()){
    System.out.println("Result not found!");
} else {
    System.out.println("Result found!");
}
```

***Note:** [`queryForObject`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcOperations.html#queryForObject-java.lang.String-org.springframework.jdbc.core.RowMapper-) throws `EmptyResultDataAccessException` for empty results. Often it is not desired behavior.*